# How to update an existing section in python config file? (Python 3.6.6)

Tags: python, python-3.x

There are already many question related to the config file, most of them are for reading and writing a new Section. My question is related to updating an existing section.

My config file rg.cnf

```
[SAVELOCATION1]
outputpath1 = TestingPath
[SAVELOCATION2]
outputpath2 = TestingPath
```

Code to update the config file:

```
def updateConfigFile(fileName, textdata):
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    cnfFile = open(fileName, "w")
    config.set("SAVELOCATION2","outputpath2",textdata)
    config.write(cnfFile)
    cnfFile.close()
```

Invoking the above method as:

```
updateConfigFile("rg.cnf","TestingPath2")
```

Running the above code gives NoSectionError:

```
configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'SAVELOCATION2'
```

Should config.set() be used only with config.add_section()? But that also does not work as it overwrites the whole file and I don't want to add any new section.

Is there any method to update the the section in the config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the config file into the `ConfigParser` before you can edit it:

```
def updateConfigFile(fileName, textdata):
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read(fileName)  # Add this line
    cnfFile = open(fileName, "w")
    config.set("SAVELOCATION2","outputpath2",textdata)
    config.write(cnfFile)
    cnfFile.close()
```